# How do i send additional object to client.PostAsync (along with file contents)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following MVC post.
It post file contents to API.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload_Post()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.InputStream.Length + 1];                     file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };
                content.Add(fileContent);
                var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
                if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message= "Created";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message= "Failed";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

What if i want to pass additional custom object (preferably json format) along with file contents?

```
CustomObject obj = new CustomObject;
obj.FirstName = "A";
object.LastName = "B";
```

Note: Following is Api method that will receive above request.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
{
    if(!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
        ....
        // save the file
        ....
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to serialize the `CustomObject` into json. e.g. using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Then you could add the `jsonString` to the `MultipartFormDataContent` like:

```
var jsonContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
content.Add(jsonContent, "CustomObject");
```

In the `Upload` API method, get the posted json content by

```
var jsonString = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["CustomObject"];
```

If the API project has a reference to class `CustomObject`, you could deserialize the `jsonString` with:

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomObject>(jsonString);
```

If not, you could also deserialize it to a `dynamic` object:

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```